# How to write transaction logs into a text file in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, events, logs

I have made a contract which generates a public event on blockchain that will notify client about a transaction.
To listen to the event I have written following snippet in geth console:

```
var event = token.CoinTransfer({}, '', function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log("Coin transfer: " + result.args.amount + " tokens were sent. Balances now are as following: \n Sender:\t" + result.args.sender + " \t" + token.coinBalanceOf.call(result.args.sender) + " tokens \n Receiver:\t" + result.args.receiver + " \t" + token.coinBalanceOf.call(result.args.receiver) + " tokens" )
});
```

Now instead of `console.log()` I want these transaction to be stored in a text file `TransactionHistory.txt`. How can we do this? Is there a better way than listening to event, to maintain transaction logs?

Answer (score 3):

Probably is best that you exec the script from a file anyway

```
 geth --exec 'loadScript("/tmp/test.js")' attach
```

Then you can direct the output, for example in Linux and Mac:

```
 geth --exec 'loadScript("/tmp/checkbalances.js")' attach > log.txt
```

Comment: It would be better if there is a command replacing "console.log". In that way I will be able to get records which I want, in the format which I like. Is there such a command(s)?

Comment: wondering about the same thing..

Answer (score 3):

The Geth console is basically a subset of Javascript, so you are limited to `console.log` and @Roland's answer of redirecting to a file could be done.

You have more flexibility by using [Ethereum JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) (see filters).  You can use a wide range of languages for JSON-RPC (some [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/945/how-can-non-javascript-applications-communicate-with-ethereum-nodes)) and its capabilities for I/O: for example you can use [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).