# How to interact with contracts in C++ application?

Tags: contract-deployment, dapps

Vast majority of resource about contracts deal with using them in web applications with JavaScript web3.

But how you interact with contracts (create, call them, make transactions) in a C++ application?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/945/how-can-non-javascript-applications-communicate-with-ethereum-nodes

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97185/can-i-interact-with-an-ethereum-contract-through-c-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of the language, you can always resort to the [JSONRPC](https://github.com/ethereum/execution-apis) to interact with the network.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I tought that there are naybe some dedicated libraries for it, as they are for js.

Comment: Yep, I tried to find the library too, but sadly there isn't a popular one for cpp.

Comment: The library could be just based on [libjson-rpc-cpp](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp/), as this is what cpp-ethereum is using.

Comment: @NewTwoEth does not support ipc connection unlike full fledged web3. This expose to the problem of not knowing to which pubsub subscription the response you re receiving corresponds to (when you have several differrent ones).