# How to use Web3 with C++?

Tags: web3js, cpp-ethereum

So this is less of a question about how to use web3 for C++ but rather where to start learning how to use and install Libraries for C++!

Related: [How to interact with contracts in C++ application?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13966/how-to-interact-with-contracts-in-c-application)

In the above related post the user was Questioning how exactly he could interact with contracts with C++...

Answer: Regardless of the language, you can always resort to the JSONRPC to
interact with the network.

OK...

So now I know that I need some sort of JSONRPC/CPP Library (also found under related post -> [lib-jsonrpc-cpp](https://github.com/cinemast/libjson-rpc-cpp/))

Great, now I know I can use one of these endpoints:

1. Ethereum https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/
2. Binance https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/

Now my questions:

1. How do I install the library? Is it like npm-js where I go to the Parent Directory and
   brew install libjson-rpc-cpp?
2. How do I work with the data? I assume C++ doesn't work the same as Javascript in the sense you run a callback function to catch errors and results?
3. Any Good tutorials out there for JSONRPC and C++ besides building my own servers?

Thank you, Im new to C++ though it is very similar to most other languages I use (web development) but i'm trying to expand my knowledge to become more well rounded.

I hope others find this useful as well!

Comment: Why do you want to use C++? Just C++ has a steep learning curve, if you add blockchain and smart contract to the mix it will be a challenge. For C++ questions it will better to ask directly in StackOverflow.com.

Comment: Because ive recently taken a liking to the complication and steep learning curve of C++, I want to Increase my overall knowledge of programming... plus web development is oversaturated and languages like CSS and javascript are too simple for my liking. Weird i know but C++ is more fun to learn to me and perfect for very custom applications.

Comment: It's perfectly fine choosing C++, other languages you may want to take a look at are Rust and Go. For C++ issues ask directly in StackOverflow.

Comment: take a look libethc on github, it is working for me