# How to write on the blockchain from vb.net?

Tags: .net

Is there any way for write on the blockchain from vb.net desktop app?
Any sample about how to do this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/945/how-can-non-javascript-applications-communicate-with-ethereum-nodes

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way for write on the blockchain from vb.net desktop app?

Yes, you should look at the [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum) project; it supports .Net languages.

> Any sample about how to do this?

The [documentation](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) contains [a section on creating and deploying smart contracts](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts/deploying/) - including videos. There is are also [tutorials in the repository](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/tree/master/src/Nethereum.Tutorials).

Comment: I am using Nethereum and .NET CORE although C# - it works really well.